# is there any method in javascript to operate a function singly for one HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-frontend

I have three box in my web page , each box includes a + button , a - button and a span with pre-assigned value as 0.
I want when I click on + or - button, the value of span get one more or less according to times of clicking + or -.
but my code doesnt work well.
what should I do ?
Thanks.

```
<div class="box">
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
    <span class="display-num">0</span>
    <button class="plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
    <span class="display-num">0</span>
    <button class="plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
    <span class="display-num">0</span>
    <button class="plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

---

```
function $(query) {
    return document.querySelector(query);
}
function $All(query) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(query);
}
const box = $All('.box');
const plusBtn = $All('.plus-btn');
const minusBtn = $All('.minus-btn');
const displayNum = $All('.display-num');

box.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        if (el.target.classList.contains('plus-btn')) {
            let num = 0;
            displayNum.forEach((e) => {
                e.innerHTML = num++;
            })
        } else if (el.target.classList.contains('minus-btn')) {
            let num = 0;
            displayNum.forEach((e) => {
                e.innerHTML = num--;
            })
        }
    }, false)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to react on the actual button being pressed, rather than checking the boxes etc, try the following:

```
plusBtn.forEach((e, idx) => {
  e.addEventListener(
    'click',
    (el) => {
      calcIt(displayNum[idx], 1);
    },
    false
  );
});

minusBtn.forEach((e, idx) => {
  e.addEventListener(
    'click',
    (el) => {
      calcIt(displayNum[idx], -1);
    },
    false
  );
});

function calcIt(element, value) {
  var num = element.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML = (+num) + value;
}
```

**Remove** the block:

```
box.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        if (el.target.classList.contains('plus-btn')) {
            let num = 0;
            displayNum.forEach((e) => {
                e.innerHTML = num++;
            })
        } else if (el.target.classList.contains('minus-btn')) {
            let num = 0;
            displayNum.forEach((e) => {
                e.innerHTML = num--;
            })
        }
    }, false)
})
```

Stackblitz:
https://jquery-rfrzsp.stackblitz.io

(https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-rfrzsp)